# Is var keyword Solves the Memory leak?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, memory-leaks, var

I know what is var(anonymous) keyword,and how to use and which place we are mainly use this keyword(LINQ - otherwise we didn't know exact return value of function that place we can use var keyword).

i know there is no difference between these two lines,my doubt is var keyword solves the memory leak problem?

For Example :

C# :

```
Window window=new Window();
var window=new Window();
```

Comment: There is no difference between those lines of code. They compile to the same thing. "var" has no impact on memory consumption - it's just a shortcut to the type name.

Comment: There are a lot of questions in this site about usage of `var`. Please make some research first.

Comment: If there is no difference between two lines of code, how could one possibly solve "the memory leak problem" (which you don't actually describe at any point in your question)? Your question is too unclear to answer in its current form.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, `var` is ***not*** the anonymous keyword. There is nothing anonymous shown in your code. Secondly, if you "know there is no difference between these two lines", why would you suspect it would change anything re a memory leak? And no: it doesn't. And no, there probably isn't a "memory leak" here in the first place.

Check whether `Window` implements `IDisposable`. If it does, and ***if*** your use of `window` is limited to the local scope, then use `using` (which will help ensure any resources are deallocated promptly, rather than waiting for the garbage collector):

```
using(var window=new Window()) {
    // NOT SHOWN: configure it, display it (modally), read the final values, etc
}
```

In the above, `var` is *purely* a convenience to avoid me needing to type "window" three times on one line.

Answer (score 1):

The `var` keyword can be used with anonymous types and can be used for type inference (the type of the variable can be inferred by the compiler). These two lines compile to exactly the same IL code:

```
Window window=new Window();
var window=new Window();
```

I'm unclear what memory leak problem you refer to, but one cannot cause a memory leak without the other doing so too.